# Unhandled promise rejection: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, http-headers

I don't know why this errors kept coming. I searched for all possible solutions on the internet still I didn't find any. Here is my node function for API call:

```
exports.GetEmployeeConfirmationList = function (req, res) {
    var request = dbConn.request();
    request.execute(storedProcedures.GetEmployeeConfirmationList).then(function (response) {
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            data: response.recordset
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.status(200).send({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
        });
    });
};
```

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code to use arrow function as `res` object is losing its scope.
When `GetEmployeeConfirmationList` callback is called it doesn't know about `res` object hence `undefined` for it. So while executing `res.status` it throws an exception and comes in `catch` block, where it again executes `res.status` and it breaks again and leads to Unhandled promise rejection.
You can capture the `err` object and `log` it in `finally` block to check if it is happening so.

```
exports.GetEmployeeConfirmationList = function (req, res) {
    var request = dbConn.request();
    request.execute(storedProcedures.GetEmployeeConfirmationList).then((response) => {
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            data: response.recordset
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(200).send({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks mate for solving it quickly , It really help.